# Hint or alert inside Android app

Tags: android

Apologies for the rough sketch.
Basically I want, the first time the user opens the app, is to draw their attention to a button and have some text like "You can click me for more information!" or something like that.

Does anyone know what this is called? Is there a name for this sort of thing - and can it be done in native Android or would I need a third party library? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Might be able to customize a `Dialog` to make this yourself.

Comment: You can simply create a view that contains that UI. Using SharedPreferences, you can set toggle its Visibility if shown already previously so it is hidden all through out its lifetime.

Comment: You need showcases a sort of tutorial for users ? If yes check this out .. https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3083 and also https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/243...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is called `ShowCase View`

Example Library : https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Edit : Note there are other libraries too. You can check [android-arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/) for more

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how the code for this works? I'm looking at `.setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))` and not really sure what that does. I presume somehow you can use that to specify which view you want to highlight?

Comment: Create a target like : `ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.btn_send, this);` and use it in setTarget(). Check also the samples that come with the library.

Comment: In my case I have a recycler view, and there's a button in each one called `android:id="@+id/expand_button"`. How can I make the ViewTarget set to that id, but only for the first item in the recycler view? Thanks

Comment: I guess that in your `ViewHolder` you can add some if conditions for your case. I can't help right now but try it and if that isn't working for you ask a new question and someone will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I sort of got it working. But I find that the `.show()`, while running, doesn't *actually* show the showcase view until I tap the screen. Do you know what could cause that?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it on your own with android's relative layout and it's textbox, by inflating the container(Relative layout) whenever you want to show, in this case at the first time of the activity and hide it later.

Try to keep the boolean value in shared preference so that your activity knows about when to show dialogue, since you would have changed the value to true at first run it will obviously hides.

However for the first time experience try the code in the given link, proof read, track and build your own later
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can design an **overlay screen** for first time instructions.This tutorial might help -http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-overlay-with-user-instructions/